# Cultural expressions to say after drinking/eating

Tags: culture

Is there a specific expression native speakers say to someone right after they have drunk/eaten something-water/drink/food- as a form of etiquette? For example, two people say *cheers* when they drink in some occasions but I am looking for expressions you might say to someone when they have eaten or drunk in informal situations while you do not have to be drinking or eating.

Example:

> A: [Finished a glass of water] Ehh!
>
> B: ................ [said
>   something to A in response to their finishing the glass of water]

Comment: You mean other than "do you want some more"? Is this something that exists in your language?

Comment: In my language (Arabic) after your drinking or eating I can say to you some words or sentences to express the idea that I wish you enjoyed it. I think the OP is asking for that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you enjoyed that! 
It seems you enjoyed that.

Delicious, eh? [for food].
Good [type of food or drink], isn't it?

Tasty [food], isn't it or wasn't it?

Refreshing [water], wouldn't you say?

Just a few ideas.

Comment: Great but I think your sentences seems to fit informal situation what if it was more formal situations like a waiter tells his guest or something like that ? Any difference ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually after you finished eating, you might ask your email partner

> How was your meal?

especially if you are treating them to the meal

To be polite, one might say to the host after finishing a meal

> That was an excellent meal.  The meat was very tender and delicious.

The type of expression you might be looking for is sometimes said *before* having a meal and is very standard

> *Bon Apetit*!

which is wishing everyone has a nice meal.  However, there i no set phrase for *after* a meal.

Culturally this will differ. Sometimes it is spoken and sometimes unspoken, for example, in some cultures if there is no leftover food it can be taken as a sign there was not enough food served.

Comment: *Bon Apetit* is French, not English.

Comment: Yes, it is still a common expression used in AmE and BrE.